# MeteorJS server crash complaining Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..../cfs/files/_tempstore/..chunk'

Tags: heroku, meteor, gridfs

Recently, we created a new upload image/PDF function.

When someone uploaded a PDF, the server still worked. But after a daily restart, the server kept crashing:

```
2022-05-25T00:52:13.648659+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:3) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747819+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/streams/legacy.js:61
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747821+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747821+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747821+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747822+00:00 app[web.1]: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.meteor/heroku_build/cfs/files/_tempstore/retailerRegistrationMedia-w6e6Kxgy8QLTgirET-0.chunk'] {
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747822+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -2,
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747823+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ENOENT',
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747823+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'open',
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747835+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/app/.meteor/heroku_build/cfs/files/_tempstore/retailerRegistrationMedia-w6e6Kxgy8QLTgirET-0.chunk'
2022-05-25T00:52:13.747836+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Investigating further, it appears that if we delete last record from the **cfs._tempstore.chunks** collection, the server can then starts correctly.

**Also, the crash ONLY happens, if the uploaded media is a PDF. No crash if uploaded media is image**

What is the cause of this error?

Relevant code to save an image below:

```
Meteor.utilities.addRetailerRegistrationMediaFile(e, function(fileId){      
  if(e.target.id == "companyACRAFile"){
    tpl.companyACRAFile = fileId;
  }else if(e.target.id == "companyShopPhotos"){
    tpl.companyShopPhotos.push(fileId);
    console.log("tpl.companyShopPhotos", tpl.companyShopPhotos);
  }     
});

Meteor.utilities.addRetailerRegistrationMediaFile = function (e, callback) {
  var $target = $(e.currentTarget)
  FS.Utility.eachFile(e, function (file) {
    RetailerRegistrationMediaObjects.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {      
      if (err) {
        return throwError(err);
      }else{
        callback(fileObj._id);
      }
    });
  });
};

// For all retailer application media
RetailerRegistrationMediaObjects = new FS.Collection("retailerRegistrationMedia", {
  stores: [
    new FS.Store.S3("registrationThumbs", {
      region: settings.public.aws_region,
      accessKeyId: settings.public.aws_key_id,
      secretAccessKey: settings.public.aws_access_key,
      bucket: settings.public.aws_bucket,
      folder: "registration/thumbs",
      transformWrite: createThumbIfImage,
    }),
    new FS.Store.S3("registration", {
      region: settings.public.aws_region,
      accessKeyId: settings.public.aws_key_id,
      secretAccessKey: settings.public.aws_access_key,
      bucket: settings.public.aws_bucket,
      folder: "registration",
    }),
  ],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 5000000, //in bytes
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ["image/*", "application/pdf"],
    },
    onInvalid: function (message) {
      if (Meteor.isClient) {
        // prepare the data for notification
        sAlert.error(message);
      }
    },
  },
});

RetailerRegistrationMediaObjects.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return true
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    return true
  },
  download: function (userId) {
    return true;
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you run your app in a docker container?

Comment: @RicardoAragão it is on heroku, i guess similar

Comment: Because the error shows a path that doesn't exist. That probably should be mapped with an external volume (I don't know heroku).

Comment: Which package you use for upload (and which version is it)?

Comment: So it doesn't cause a server crash, but some leftover files (in the file system) cause a crash at startup? I have a couple of strategies I would use 1) try and check a file for integrity after upload (and clean up file system?) 2) Try and clean up before Meteor starts to prevent this failure